# MFSideMenu side Viewcontroller not navigate to Specific view controller in Tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am using MFSideMenu in TabBarController In SideMenu i have added UITableview so when i click on cell then it navigate to another view controller but its not navigate to that view controller

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

centerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tabbarcontroller"];

TabViewController1 *tableView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabViewController1"];
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableView];


TabViewController2 *tableView2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabViewController2"];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableView2];


 centerViewController.viewControllers = @[nav1,nav2];
 UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideViewController"];

 container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController
                                                        leftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController
                                                        rightMenuViewController:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = container;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

**SideMenu.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


 ViewController3 *objEdit =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController3"];

 AppDelegate *objApp = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) objApp.centerViewController.navigationController;

 NSLog(@"navigationcontroller :%@",objApp.centerViewController.navigationController);

 [navigationController pushViewController:objEdit animated:YES];

[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objApp.centerViewController is  tabbarcontroller, So you need to find out selected view controller from tabor controller first.  If you want to push controller in selected tab, You should get Navigationcontroller  from SelectedViewCOntroller of tabbarcontroller.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)   objApp.centerViewController.selectedViewController;

  [navigationController pushViewController:objEdit animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help  its working now what  a silly mistake i did :)